# why is the pixel coordinate in x,y plane x + y*width?

Tags: opengl, pixel, getpixel

I'm currently learning about opengl and I don't understand how the pixel coordinate works.

First, the x, y coordinates would go into a double loop until x < width and y < height, and within that loop, the pixel coordinate is equal to x + y*width and I don't understand why this is so.

Comment: What do you mean by "the pixel coordinate"? Images are two-dimensional, and thus have 2 coordinates, usually called X and Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This results from how the pixels are stored in memory.

Here's a sketch of the pixels:

```
|-------width-------|
+ + + + + + + + + + +  <--- row_0
+ + + + + + + + + + +  <--- row_1
+ + + + + + + + + + +  <--- row_2
       .....
+ + + + + + + + + + +  <--- row_n
0 1 ...         ... m  columns
```

This is laid out in memory in row major mode:

```
[row_0,row_1,...row_n]
```

Since each row has `width` pixels, then the `(x,y)` pixel, meaning the x-th column in y-th row, is stored in position `x+y*width.`